# Can someone tell me the differences between the vowel system in Canadian English and the one in General American?

Tags: phonetics, vowels

I am interested in knowing what are the vowels found in Canadian English, more particularly in Toronto and Montreal. I know that the low back merger occurred where both /ɔ/ and /ɒ/ merged into /ɑ/ in Canada (if I'm not mistaken). Does this mean that you can't find either of those vowels in Canadian English?

I'm having a hard time finding a vowel chart for Canadian English, so if someone could post one or simply describe the vowel system and provide a few examples, it would be really helpful!